# Connection string 'server' keyword is not supported

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, web-config, azure-web-app-service, connection-string

I deployed an ASP.NET MVC 5 website to the MS Azure platform. But when my web app tries to connect to the database, the app throws an exception:

> 'server' keyword is not supported

I took connection string (ado.net) from Azure portal.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NiqaatyEntities" 
         connectionString="Server=tcp:ServerName.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Login;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I changed:

- serverName
- DatabaseName
- Login
- password

I'm using a database-first approach with EDMX.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're using a database-first approach with EDMX, so you need to use a special type of connection string which looks like:

> metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
>   connection string="data source=(local);initial
>   catalog=test;integrated
>   security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"

Inside this connection string, you'll have the `provider connection string` attribute which is your connection string:

> Server=tcp:ServerName.database.windows.net,1433;Initial
>   Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=False;User
>   ID=Login;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection
>   Timeout=30;