# Connection string keyword 'server' is not Supported

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, connection-string

I am deploying an ASP.NET Core MVC app with VS2017 on MacBook. When I want to update my database with

```
dotnet ef database update  --project MyProjectName
```

I get an error:

> Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported. For a possible alternative, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142181.

I have installed `System.Data.SqlClient` package on my project and I have read similar questions but none of them solve my problem. What is the problem with this code? I am really getting confused.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=my_ip; Database=my_db; User Id=sa; Password=my_pass;",
    "providerName": "System.Data.SqlClient"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps use Uri instead?

Comment: hi @jspcal . Thank for comment. I tried every method and even I have used `Data Source` and `Initial Catalog` but nothing have changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544978/connection-string-server-keyword-is-not-supported ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server try this connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=35.xx.xx.xxxx;Initial Catalog=nmmm;Integrated Security=False;User ID=nmmm;Password=vvvvv;"
```

add if you use sql server you should have this in startup

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Thank you Serge. In this way error changes to `Connection string keyword 'initial catalog' is not supported`

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It is Sql server @Serge

Comment: @BehzadHassani Can you post your startup file too , pls?

Comment: @BehzadHassani Why then link shows SQLIte?

Comment: Just use https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ to get the connectionstrings. Funny enough "Initial Catalog" is NOT HOW YOU DO IT. Read the documentation, read https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @TomTom I am sorry, but  I've been always using Initial Catalog for ms sql server and never had any problem

Comment: @Serge I don’t know. But I am using vs on mac. Does it make problem?

Comment: @TomTom does it make problem If I use vs on mac?It is my first time to use vs on mac and I am not familiar with issues